# Expression Engine install differences

Tags: php, configuration-files, expressionengine

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this but I have a site with a staging and beta install of expression engine. Same versions same files everything appears to be identical. The config files are the same except for the url differences however the two sites behave differently for a number of extensions/modules. One issue was that on the staging site the previous developer had a template embedding another template and using it in a loop to execute another query so something like this:

```
    {!-- template uri /example/uri --}

        start loop

        {embed="template/.thistemplate" id="{id}"}


        end loop


   {!--end template--}
```

This worked perfectly fine on staging but on the beta install it did not, it actually only embedded the last id passed through for every item in the loop which resulted in the same result for the whole loop.

To get this particular issue working I rewrote the code so that it didn't embed anything but I am having lots of other issues that are similar in the fact that they work on staging and not beta and I am wondering if anyone out there knows of any places where settings could drastically alter the behavior of the site.

Answer (score 0):

In four years of EE development, I've never seen an issue like this. My only guess is that your beta environment may not use a supported version of PHP or may have modules configured in a way that parses EE's PHP code differently than your staging server does. If you haven't already done so, check the beta server's settings to make sure it fits [EE's requirements](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/installation/requirements.html). It's difficult to give you any other pointers without further information. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the 2 sites are not truly in sync.

How was the 2nd site split off from the first site?

Were both the database and the filesystem cloned at the same time?

I would consider making a new snapshot of staging and using that as your beta site.

Comment: I am not sure as to how the 2nd site was created, I picked this up from a team that was let go. When I got the project beta had significantly more data and template style related content to it. There was one new module but it is not dealing with any of the actions or hooks that would affect other modules and pages